# Is it possible to migrate Hyper-V VMs from Windows 10 to Server 2016 host?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10, windows-server-2016

Official MSFT documentation does not answer this question directly so I decided to ask it here. Will VM migration from Windows 10 x64 (latest build/Anniversary update) to Server 2016 be possible? I don't speak about live migration (which is not supported by client Hyper-V) but wondering about some more convenient way of move all my VMs besides Import/Export function which will work assuming I have 2 host machines running side by side on the same network and can provide them with shared storage.

Comment: You don't need shared storage to use Import/Export!?

Comment: `wondering about some more convenient way of move all my VMs besides Import/Export function` - Are you asking if it's possible to migrate them at all or are you asking if there's another way to do it other than importing/exporting?

Comment: I expect that Import/Export will work though it would be nice to confirm this if somebody tried already. I would prefer to have something similar to live migration/move for switched off VM to another server so that I select target server and just wait for completion :) It seems that my client Hyper-V only offers me to move storage but not VM...

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear.  If you mean "Is there a way to put all the files that make up a VM somewhere that the Server 2016 host can use them as a VM" then that's "export."  And, yes, it works.  You can then import the exported VM.

If you exported it to the location that you want it to stay, you can do an in-place import that skips copying the VM again.